# Unit test fails in TFS but not locally (NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, tfs, moq, tfs-2015

I have the following unit test (some things renamed but otherwise identical) that runs fine locally, and passes as expected.

```
[TestClass, ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class SearchControllerTests
{
    private Mock<IRepository> _repository;
    private Mock<ICrypter> _crypter;
    private SearchController _controller;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _repository = new Mock<IRepository>();
        _crypter = new Mock<ICrypter>();
        _controller = new SearchController(_repository.Object, _crypter.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SearchViewSimple()
    {
        var result = _controller.Search() as PartialViewResult;

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual("Search", result.ViewBag.Title);
    }
}
```

It passes in TFS 2015 as well. However we are upgrading to TFS 2015 Update 2 and there the test fails in that environment with an identical build process. A NullReferenceException is thrown on this line in the initialize method.

```
_crypter = new Mock<ICrypter>();
```

ICrypter is a very simple wrapper for SCrypt using CryptSharp:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ICrypter), typeof(Crypter))]
namespace ProjectNameRemoved.Cryptography
{
    public interface ICrypter
    {
        string GetHash(string value);
    }

    public class Crypter : ICrypter
    {
        public string GetHash(string value)
        {
            // Removed
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some difference between TFS 2015 and 2015 Update 2 that would cause something like this? Or perhaps some sort of dependency issue where CryptSharp isn't being downloaded? External connections are fine in the build and the packages seem to have been updated without issue or warning.

Comment: Not a direct response to your question, but TFS 2015 Update 2 was a pretty [buggy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2016/04/26/heads-up-tfs-2015-2-1-coming/) release. So much so they released an update to the update(!), TFS 2015 Update 2.1. Are your builds TF or XAML build?

Comment: @pero TF - I will confirm that we are on Update 2 and not Update 2.1 maybe that is it? The age of this blog post makes me think we might be on 2.1

Comment: Suggest you to reconfigure build agent and did this only occurs this specific build?

Comment: Not sure if this is related- but a lot of my builds (using the TF builds not XAML) broke when upgrading.. I found the issue to be that the *Visual Studio Version* in a few of the build steps had changed. We set the value to *Latest* and it fixed it.

Comment: Dears, you should post as Answer not as Comment, so when the OP finds the problem, he can let the community know the right solution

Comment: Following Giulio's comment, it is not clear if the issue was caused by TFS2015 update 2 and solved by TFS2015 update 2.1 or not.